# How do I change the build's SDK version in Xcode?

Tags: java, xcode, sdk, version

I'm using Xcode 2.5 on Mac 10.4.11 PPC. `javac -version` returns 1.5.x yet when I imported my source code and tried to build it in Xcode, I get errors all over because `generics`, `annotations`, and `for-each loops are not supported in -source 1.3`.

[image: sdk setting]

I thought I found the setting to change the source version in Xcode in the above but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I went through the `build.xml` file of the Xcode project and found the source and target fields and just changed em from 1.3 and 1.2 respectively to 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

Google turned this up: [But it does seem very old](http://cordney.com/2005/09/24/java-5-setup-on-os-x/)